# Exception in Storm Topology having WindowedBolt

Tags: apache-storm

I am trying to run topology which has Windowed Bolt, but getting following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.storm.topology.WindowedBoltExecutor.declareOutputFields(WindowedBoltExecutor.java:309)
    at org.apache.storm.topology.TopologyBuilder.getComponentCommon(TopologyBuilder.java:432)
    at org.apache.storm.topology.TopologyBuilder.createTopology(TopologyBuilder.java:120)
    at Main.main(Main.java:23)
```

I have created custom windowed bolt by extending BaseWindowedBolt.

Topology code :

```
TopologyBuilder builder = new TopologyBuilder();
        builder.setSpout("integer", new RandomIntegerSpout(), 1);
        builder.setBolt("tumblingsum", new CustomTumblingSumWindow().withTumblingWindow(new Duration(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)),1).shuffleGrouping("integer");
        builder.setBolt("final", new ResultBolt(),1).shuffleGrouping("tumblingsum");
        Config config = new Config();
        config.put(Config.TOPOLOGY_WORKERS, 1);
        StormSubmitter.submitTopology("Test-Windowing-Topology", config, builder.createTopology());
```

**Storm Version is 1.2.2**

If I run above topology without WindowedBolt then it is working.

Am I missing anything?

Thanks

Comment: I used submitTopologyWithProgressBar instead of submitTopology and it worked

Answer (score 0):

The line you're getting an exception from is https://github.com/apache/storm/blob/v1.2.2/storm-core/src/jvm/org/apache/storm/topology/WindowedBoltExecutor.java#L309.

My guess would be that your bolt is returning null from `getComponentConfiguration`. This looks like a bug, but you can work around it by returning an empty map from `getComponentConfiguration`.

Raised https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/STORM-3211 to fix it.